# Расшифровка md5 в PHP

Tags: php, md5

Есть ли команда для расшифровки md5 хэша в PHP?
В PHP есть команда md5($variable), есть ли обратная команда?

Comment: Ну оказывается уже придумали расшифровку к md5, что самое небезопасное стало.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нету, это необратимое шифрование.

Comment: Есть ли алгоритмы шифрования с обратной расшифровкой в PHP?

Comment: Вроде как есть - base64.

Comment: http://php.su/functions/?base64-encode
http://php.su/functions/?base64-decode

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Нету, команды `MD5` и `SHA1` не дешифруются. Вы можете запросить у пользователя пароль, например, зашифровать его с помощью `MD5` и сверить с тем значением, шифрованным, которое хранится в базе данных. Если значения совпадают, то все ок. Но лучше `MD5` не используйте, а используйте более крипто-стойкий алгоритм `SHA1`.